# Python Log Name Not Showing in Google Cloud Platform Console Log View

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform

I'm setting up a Google Cloud Function. When I try to set a python log name, I'm not able have the Google Cloud Platform Logging console show the log name in the console log window. Only the 'name' of the cloud function is shown. The reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to easily identify which part of my function output which log entries.

I've tried to insert this in my main.py file:

```
from google.cloud import logging as cloudlogging
import logging
lg_client = cloudlogging.Client()
lg_handler = lg_client.get_default_handler()
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger("foobarlog")
cloud_logger.addHandler(lg_handler)
```

So as per above, the logname is set to "foobarlog". But in the Google Cloud Console log below, only the function name "Download" is shown. I haven't been able to figure out how to show "foobarlog" in the log summaries as per screenshot below.

Screenshot: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLS4Z.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99ROC.png)

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the last two log entries shown in the screenshot. One has a Traceback and the other finished execution status. It could be the case that the code with your logging didn't even ran. But let's see those log contents first.

Comment: Hi @fhenriques - the code ran. I believe this might be a GCP issue. I will submit a feature request instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just reproduced your case and here is how I managed to add a custom tag as you want.

My example Function

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('foolog')

from google.cloud import logging as glogging
client = glogging.Client()
cloud_log = client.logger('foolog')

handler = client.get_default_handler()
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger('foolog')
cloud_logger.addHandler(handler)

def test_logging(request):
    logger.info("--- START ---")

    cloud_logger.debug("cloud_logger.debug")
    cloud_logger.info("cloud_logger.info")
    cloud_logger.warn("cloud_logger.warn")
    cloud_logger.error("cloud_logger.error")

    logger.info("--- END ---")
    return 'OK'
```

After that you can go to the Log Viewer and set the selected resources to Global, select the Json payload of the desired log > python_logger > add field summary line.

[image]

Finally you will see your tag in stackdriver

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go, that's amazing!

Comment: @Chris32 `cloud_log = client.logger('foolog')` is this line even being used?